# how can I query multiple table to get the data from collections in mongodb using pymongo

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have 5 collections

```
user : { "id": 1}
```

```
group: { "gid": 13, "name": "group1"}
```

```
subgroup: {"sgid": 22, "gid": 13, "name": "sgroup1"}
```

```
maps : {"userId": 1, "id": 10, "mapId": 13}
```

```
data: {"sgid": 22, "somedata": "somedata"}
```

I have the current `user` `id`, now using `userId` I need to get `mapId` from `maps`, using `mapId` get the `sgid` from `subgroup`, from `sgid` get the `data`, along with the data i need `groupname`  and `subgroup` name.

Comment: What field in the `user` collection document can be used to get the related `userId` in the `maps` collection?  What field in a `subgroup` collection document is related to `mapId`?

Comment: I get the userId from token. I want to use that id, in user id = userId in maps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need something like this:

The trick basically is to use the [$lookup](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) to do the "join" and additionally `$unwind` to deconstruct the result (also `$lookup` also works with an array).

And the last stage is `$project` to get only values you want.

```
db.user.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "maps",
      "localField": "id",
      "foreignField": "userId",
      "as": "map"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$map"
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "subgroup",
      "localField": "map.mapId",
      "foreignField": "gid",
      "as": "subgroup"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$subgroup"
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "data",
      "localField": "subgroup.sgid",
      "foreignField": "sgid",
      "as": "data"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$data"
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "group",
      "localField": "subgroup.gid",
      "foreignField": "gid",
      "as": "group"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$group"
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "data": "$data.somedata",
      "groupname": "$group.name",
      "subgroupname": "$subgroup.name"
    }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/DPcwd8psFkb)

By the way, if you need 4 ´$lookup` maybe Mongo is not the best DB (but this is only an opinion).

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm getting the output, but there is one catch, i need output in [{ "groupName": "someGroup", "subGroupName": "someSubGroupName", "data": [ {somedata}, {somedata}], there are multiple data under same group and subgroup.

Comment: Then in the `$project` stage use `"data": 1,` like [this example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/9vOMX-5SbjU)